# Finding word collocations in Java

Tags: java, nlp

I am trying to find [collocations (PDF)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/fsnlp/promo/colloc.pdf) in Java.

I know [NLTK](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.collocations-module.html) has a collocations module, but do not want to use Jython.

I looked at OpenNLP and GATE, but they did not seem to have a collocation finder.

Does anybody know a free open source collocation finder implemented 
in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the best ready to use algorithm for collcation is [xTract](http://dragon.ischool.drexel.edu/xtract.asp) in DragonToolkit it uses basic statistics collocation features like lingpipe and more sophisticated such as POS tagging

Answer (score 2):

- http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/implement/kolokacje/implement.shtml.
  ([java source code](http://duch.mimuw.edu.pl/~abuczyns/kolokacje/download/kolokacje_121.zip))
- LingPipe is a commercial library. http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/interestingPhrases/read-me.html

Answer (score 1):

Through [Grant Ingersoll's overview of new features in Mahout](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mahout-scaling/index.html) I discovered that Apache Mahout now has a [collocations feature](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/collocations.html). This is open source, in Java, but requires Hadoop infrastructure.